# Std vector resizing

Tags: c++, vector, resize, std

I have some std::vector and I have to resize it with some default value. Here is the code:

```
static int Counter = 0;
class Data
{
   /* ... */
   Data() { 
      Counter++; 
      std::cout << Counter << std::endl;
   }
};

std::vector<Data> mArray;

for (int i=0; i <= 200; ++i)
{
   mArray.push_back(Data());
}

// And resizing somewhere:
std::cout << "Resizing!\n";
mArray.resize(400, Data());
```

As I understand, after inserting 200 items, I can resize it with `resize` function which takes new size and default value for each new element.

When I run that program I see:

```
0
1
2
...
199
200
Resizing
201
```

Why does only 1 item is inserted after resizing?

Comment: to default construct 200 items, declare the vector as follows: `std::vector<Data> mArray(200);`. This will save you the loop!

Comment: @Nim only for this case. In constructor there is also inialization of inner members for each object. And the data is different.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're only seeing a count from your default constructor, when the entries being added are copy constructed. You'll have to add a copy constructor that counts copies as well:

```
   Data(const Data& other) { 
      // Actual copying code, whatever that may be
      Counter++; 
      std::cout << Counter << std::endl;
   }
```

Comment: That's not likely to end well.

Comment: copy ctor can be elided, so it's not necessary you will see any counting.

Comment: Because copying occurs for reasons other than adding new entries to the vector. You're likely to end up with a random mess.

Comment: @Gene: If the copy is actually being done, the copy constructor will run. Copying can be elided in the case of RVO, for example, but that's not the case here.

Comment: @Mark: If it's the OP's intent to do instance counting, the counter had better be updated in every constructor. If it's his intent just to find out how many entries are getting added to the vector, he'd certainly be better off querying the vector for its size.

Comment: @Fred:  If he intends it to be used as instance counting, he will also need to decrement the counter in the destructor.  Otherwise anytime the vector's allocated space is resized (and all the elements are copied), his "instance counter" will continue to increase despite the fact that he only has 400 non-destroyed objects (after the resize call).  If he were to call any other algorithms (e.g. sort), the same thing would happen.

Comment: @Zac: That assumes the instance counter is intended to be an ACTIVE instance counter. If the intent is to have a count of all the instances ever created, it would never be decremented. Again, using an instance counter isn't the best way to find out how many instances are added to the vector.

Answer (score 5):

Because the default constructor is called once: std::vector copies its contents, so you're actually copying the same object 200 times.

Answer (score 3):

Because resize will use the copy constructor to insert new elements and for this reason, the default constructor is called only once.

Answer (score 2):

Because the other 199 Data instances are created by copying the Data instance that you pass to resize() via its copy constructor.

Answer (score 2):

You are printing out `Counter++`, not the size of your vector (since only 1 `Data` object is created to initialize the rest of the vector, it only gets incremented once).